# Vue.js передача в props вычисляемого свойства computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

Есть вот такой элемент в style которого я передаю динамическую длину зависящую от длины массива с элементами.

```
computed: {
    elementStyle() {
      var fileElementWidth = 69 + 5;
      var width = this.files.length * (fileElementWidth);
      if (this.allowableWidth - width < fileElementWidth)
        width = '100%';
      else
        width += 'px';

      return { width };
    }
}
```

И если оставшегося места не хватает под элемент, то я задаю ширину в 100% и новый добавленный элемент переносится на новую строку.

```
props: ['files', 'allowableWidth']
```

Вот props, который компонент принимает.
Массив с файлами и допустимую длину.

```
<row
    :files="files"
    :allowableWidth="width"
/>

data () {
    return {
      files: [{name: 'name1'}],
      count: 0,
      width: 800
    };
}
```

Во второй prop сначала передается свойство width у родительского компонента.
Но позже я меняю длину элемента DOM и я должен начать передавать в дочерний компонент результат computed - resizedWidth.

```
computed: {
    resizedWidth() {
      return this.$el.clientWidth;
    }
}
```

Сразу я его передать не могу, т.к родительский компонент еще не добавлен в DOM, не могу получить его свойство.

---

Соберу теперь все в одном месте.
Идея в том, что при изменении CSS Width у родителя, эта же width передавалась в дочерний компонент каким-то образом, чтобы понять переносить мне уже элемент или нет.
Computed свойство я не могу передать в prop дочернему компоненту.
Хотел как-то реализовать это через LifeCycles, но получаются только костыли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если DOM еще не готов, можно дождаться его полного построение с помощью this.$nextTick();

Можете в хуке mounted у родительского компонента навешать слушатель события resize.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
```

В методе handleResize уже изменять this.width = this.$el.clientWidth; и передавать в prop (:width="width") дочернего. У дочернего компонента изменения нужно отслеживать с помощью

```
watch: {
  width(newValue, oldValue) {}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Наконец-то кто-то помог)